# WPF: Get closed window result in app.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Seemed to have this working before, just making a login system for my application. Got it checking a local database for users and creating an object with the user information. But when the user logs in the login window should close and display the main window.

As this happens I need to access data from the login window which I have done like so:

```
protected override void OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!AreSettingsSet())
            {
                Window LoginWindow = new Views.LoginWindow();
                LoginWindow.ShowDialog(); 
                //Waits until closed.

                //If the login form was closed properly, handle the user
                if (LoginWindow.DialogResult == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Logged in correctly!");
                    //Add the user to the list of logged users
                    User returned = LoginWindow.returnUser;
                    MessageBox.Show("First name:" + returned.FirstName);
                    LoggedUsers.Add(returned);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Unexpected window close, possible Alt + F4, shutdown!
                    MessageBox.Show(Messages.UnexpectedClose);
                    this.Shutdown();
                }

                // Recheck the settings now that the login screen has been closed.
                if (!AreSettingsSet())
                {

                }
            }

            this.MainWindow = new Views.Main();
            this.MainWindow.Show();
        }
```

Here is the LoginWindow:

```
//Give App access to user object outside of this form
        public User returnUser
        {
            get
            {
                return user;
            }
        }

        //Public user object, start empty
        User user = new User();

        //Check the login
        private void doLogin(string email, string password)
        {
            //Connect to database
            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(Settings.ConnectionString))
            {
                //Try and open the connection
                try
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //Unable to connect to database, just return
                    MessageBox.Show(Messages.UnableOpenConnection);
                    return;
                }

                string salt = null;
                bool found = false;

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Queries.GetSalt, myConnection))
                {
                    //Fetch the salt for the entered email address
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", email));
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    //Read the data
                    reader.Read();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        salt = reader["salt"].ToString();
                        found = true;
                    }
                    //Close the reader
                    reader.Close();
                }
                if (found == true)
                {
                    if (salt.Length == 32)
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Queries.GetSingleUser, myConnection))
                        {
                            //Salt the password
                            string saltedPassword = Encryption.sha256(password + salt);

                            //Add paramaters
                            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", email));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", saltedPassword));

                            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                            reader.Read();
                            if (reader.HasRows)
                            {
                                //Populate the login instance
                                user.ID = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["id"]);
                                user.FirstName = reader["firstname"].ToString();
                                user.LastName = reader["lastname"].ToString();
                                user.Email = reader["email"].ToString();
                                user.Permissions = Convert.ToInt16(reader["permissions"]);

                                //Close the reader
                                reader.Close();

                                //See if user has a thumbnail picture and save it's location
                                string thumbLoc = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() +
                                    "\\Users\\DisplayPictures\\" +
                                    user.FirstName + user.LastName + ".png";

                                if (File.Exists(@thumbLoc))
                                {
                                    user.ThumbLoc = thumbLoc;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    user.ThumbLoc = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Users\\DisplayPictures\\user.png";
                                }

                                //Found user and created object, close this window safley
                                this.DialogResult = true;
                                this.Close();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Unable to find a user
                                MessageBox.Show(Messages.NoUserFound);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Salt is the incorrect length
                        MessageBox.Show(Messages.InvalidSalt);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Messages.NoUserFound);
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm getting an error here `User returned = LoginWindow.returnUser;` saying:

> 'System.Windows.Window' does not contain a definition for 'returnUser'
>   and no extension method 'returnUser' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'System.Windows.Window' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Please help me resolve this, and if i'm going about the login wrong please suggest changes!

Comment: Put a using block on the showdialog call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you declared the `LoginWindow` variable of type `Window`, instead of `LoginWindow`. `LoginWindow` has a `returnUser` property, but `Window` doesn't. Change the declaration to this:

```
Views.LoginWindow loginWindow = new Views.LoginWindow();
```

or just

```
var loginWindow = new Views.LoginWindow();
```

BTW, the convention in C# is to name local variables in `camelCase`, not `PascalCase`. For types and public members (methods, properties etc) you should use `PascalCase`. So the `LoginWindow` variable should be named `loginWindow`, and the `returnUser` property should be `ReturnUser`.

Comment: Thanks! And I will change the camelCase and PascalCases and keep it in mind! Am I doing the logging in correctly? Or in an okay way?